# What is a scientific term for a "game trail"

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, science, academia, biology

I've been trying to find scientific research concerning animals' tendency to adhere to certain worn paths, or *"game trails"*. However, I have found very little and suspect the problem to be that a different, more scientific word is usually used instead.

A "game trail" is a clear path in a forest lacking substantial undergrowth due to the frequent passage of animals, such as deer.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U! The following is not an answer, but it's possibly of interest: "*A [trackway](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trackway) is an ancient route of travel for people or animals*".

Comment: This isn't an answer either, but may have some useful info: http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/10723/how-can-i-recognize-a-game-trail  A phrase that comes up in this Q&A is "path of least resistance".  [Desire path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desire_path) isn't an answer either, but may lead somewhere.  This is a fascinating question.  +1

Comment: Contemporary study of animal behavior is called 'ethology'. Scientifically, animals are not 'game'—leaving aside the putative origins of science as an evolution of tracking. In ethology, I don't know of any more technical term than 'path' (or '[animal] path', bearing in mind that humans are also animals) and 'trail' (or '[animal] trail'). 'Path' or 'trail', however, may be modified by various adjectives that suggest scientific distinctions between types: 'collective' path or trail, for example, distinguishes what you might call a 'game trail' from others not distinguishable as 'trails'.

Comment: So, search for *+"animal path" ethology* or something similar, then refine the search as you focus on your area of interest (for example, *+"collective path" ethology psychology*).

Comment: Also, see the answers to this question on ELU (with word choices related to animals as well as people): [What is the word for a path that is made naturally by the action of people walking?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/89741/what-is-the-word-for-a-path-that-is-made-naturally-by-the-action-of-people-walki)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

- It seems that you have become motivated to find a "Scientific
  Definition" for the term "Game Trail" for the purpose of scientific
  research.  I am going to answer your question to the best of my
  knowledge by trying to provide an answer that is helpful to your
  studies versus just offering various definitions.  I perceive
  language as being a vehicle for communication and understanding,
  using my current perception I think you have the correct definition
  to achieve understanding.
      Scientific research that would help explain certain animals tendencies to adhere to certain paths could be obtained and learned
  about scientifically through many various fields of study.  I am
  going to provide information focuses primarily on the study of animal
  behavior regarding Animal Cognition.  This method of scientific
  research would seemingly be obtained through visual stimuli during
  such studies to understand the actions of animals.
      After doing some brief research into animal behavior to offer some scientific explanation and reasoning here are my results.
  Simply stated animals are motivated to survive as a primary
  predisposition.  Taking into account that idea it would seem that
  animals would react similarly in a similar environment to efficiently
  achieve that predisposition as a general rule,  This would mean that 
  various stimuli in such similar shared environment may have
  encouraged animals to act in a way that would create infrastructure
  in the environment to help them survive.  If an animal chose a path
  because of the nearby resources necessary for it's survival then it's
  likely other animals would choose similar paths resulting in leaving 
  behind signs in the form of stimuli such as,but not limited to;
  scent, structures (dens, beds, dams, etc...) food, and broken plant
  cover.  The variables of each animals affect on that path would be of
  scientific importance but as a simple perspective it would seem even 
  after the first animal took a path for the previous reasons the next 
  animal in the area may find that path easier to take being as how the
  first animal would have broken some of the plant cover this would of 
  course be true for each animal that travels such path until you end
  up with a little road or "game trail".  It would also be apparent
  that an animal would choose to use such path often after the first
  time of use since the reasons for taking the unbeaten path were
  substantial enough for the survival of said animal to rely on taking 
  an unbeaten path.  This is just a very simple explanation to give
  examples as to why an animal takes such action.      I would like to
  state a perspective in relation to understanding other     species
  actions with the reminder that humans are animals that have a
  predisposition to survive as well.  Of course    living things are
  generally motivated for their survival with the    natural goal of
  continuing their species,  observation using the    scientific method
  of modern scientific culture would support such    statements.  That
  being stated we as an intelligent species have also    chosen to
  create and share paths for our survival in the hunt for    resources
  and an improved ability to survive.  These days it's easy    to
  forget such things since we are creating things such as shared
  routes of travel for things other than simple "Survival".

  I would advise you to look into the science of psychology and
  findings throughout the study of animal behavior as well as
  comparative psychology,  ethology, behavioral ecology, and
  evolutionary psychology, and cognitive ethology if you are trying to 
  locate Scientific avenues for research information in the scientific 
  communities.  I believe I have answered you question and offered
  thoughts to help you in your research.  Thanks for everyone that has 
  participated in this conversation in the pursuit of answering the
  question and most of all thanks for allowing me the opportunity to
  participate as well.  Sincerely

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about science, but in general usage it is **paths of desire** (or, as Wikipedia calls them, [desire paths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desire_path)).

Answer (score -1):

**Spoor**, according to [Oxford Living Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/spoor):

> The track or scent of an animal.

Two of their example sentences:

> ‘He found the spoor easily enough and followed it for about a minute, but then it forked.’
>
> ‘They followed cattle spoors for about seven kilometres and found 66 of the cattle scattered over a distance of 10 km.’

Used [in academia](https://zslpublications.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/j.1469-7998.1997.tb05805.x):

> Tracking, the reconstruction of activity from the **spoor** of animals, is an age‐old technique that is still frequently used by modern‐day hunter/gatherer communities.

Attribution:

"Spoor | Definition of Spoor in English by Oxford Dictionaries." Oxford Dictionaries | English. Accessed May 26, 2018. https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/spoor.

Stander, P.e., Ii. Ghau, D. Tsisaba, Ii. Oma, and |.| Vi. "Tracking and the Interpretation of Spoor: A Scientifically Sound Method in Ecology." Journal of Zoology 242, no. 2 (2009): 329-41. doi:10.1111/j.1469-7998.1997.tb05805.x.